# How to work with tabbed signup/signin form using devise in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am a new to the whole rails environment and learning to implement 'devise' gem for my project. Currently I have a tabbed signup/signin form.

[image]

I have generated the devise views and modified the `/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` to show this kind of tabbed form.Now functionality wise everything working fine. But there are several issues.

1. When I am hitting http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up it still shows the devise old signup form. I want to show the same form with the `Registration` tab activated.
2. On the `Register` tab if I submit the form with some error (Empty Email/Password), it is again redirecting to the default device registration form to show up the error messages.

I just want to get rid of this default registration page and want to use my `Register` tab for all signup purposes.

This question may sounds very basic, but I have no idea how to customize it.
Please help.

Comment: The registrations view is `/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I like to make reference to the comment from @max as an answer, so that others could take that as an answer to this question.

I believe you are getting those errors because you are hacking your session views in Devise. The registration view in Devise is at `/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`. You have to refactor your code to do away with the errors.

*Answer is courtesy of @max*